# Teams: "error rendering message" in Adaptive Card (Bot Framework) for some SQL content

Tags: c#, botframework, teams-toolkit

**Update** for below question: it is a confirmed bug and tracked here https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/9392

Sometimes Teams would show me an error "Error encountered while rendering this message" without any further detail. I narrowed the problem down to this SQL query:

```sql
"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT VisitorId) AS UniqueVisitors FROM sitedata WHERE eventdate>='2023-08-01' AND eventdate<'2023-08-08' AND Site =='foo.bar.com' AND Url RLIKE '^http?s://foo.bar.com/([^/]*)/answers/?'"
```

To render the card I'm using this code:

```
var cardContent = new AdaptiveCardTemplate(cardTemplate).Expand(
            new
            {
                Query = sql
            }
        );

        var replyActivity = MessageFactory.Attachment
        (
            new Attachment
            {
                ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(cardContent),
            }
        );

        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(replyActivity);
```

The card's relevant portion is this:

```json
{
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "${query}",
      "wrap": true,
      "fontType": "Monospace",
      "color": "Dark",
      "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
      "separator": true
    }
```

I tried to figure out what exactly it is that breaks the rendering but the results are non-conclusive. If I change the SQL to this, the output will break:

```sql
"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT VisitorId) AS UniqueVisitors FROM sitedata WHERE eventdate>='2023-08-01' AND"
```

If I change it further and only remove the last  `AND`, it renders just fine:

```sql
"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT VisitorId) AS UniqueVisitors FROM sitedata WHERE eventdate>='2023-08-01'"
```

As a workaround I wrapped the assignment into `WebUtility.HtmlEncode(sql)`and that fixes the issue. I would love to understand what the problem is and how to solve it properly.

Comment: Regarding the first query, it would seem that whatever the response is being returned, the type or formatting isn't correct for rendering the adaptive card. My guess is that the response only sometimes includes incorrect characters resulting in it only sometimes being an issue. I would debug your app and see what is being returned when the issue occurs. Regarding the second query, it makes sense it would fail as the `AND` suggests there are additional conditions but nothing follows. I'm guessing an error is being returned. The last query renders because the query "works".

Comment: As for the `HtmlEncode()` method, it's taking whatever the offensive characters are and converting them into something the adaptive card can handle. In this case, an HTML encoded response. Or, as I'm unfamiliar with that tool, at a minimum, wrapping the value in HTML. To be honest, using this method may be just fine even if you do figure out the query is doing. Just had a thought...perhaps the query response has quotes in it which is interfering with the quotes in `"${query"`??? Something to check, perhaps.

Comment: Please note: this is not about invalid SQL queries. The SQL queries are only part of what should be displayed and are causing the error in Teams. Removing specific portions (combinations of chars) from the SQL prevents the issue to happen.

Comment: Hmm. Well, I'm not sure what to tell you. You asked, "to understand what the problem is and how to solve it". From my perspective this _is_ about invalid SQL queries _if_ the SQL query is returning a value the adaptive card can't handle. And, of course, the query is going to work if you remove the parts that are seemingly returning an error or a response with invalid characters. This is just my two cents on the matter. Perhaps debugging and stepping thru to see what is happening would shed some light...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a confirmed bug and tracked here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/9392